# Please see image and calculate for combined stress and deformation

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, simulation

[image: Cross section is 0.0031771m². From left to right, the forces are, 300kN, 320KN, 350KN, 360KN] This image is from an assignment

I am struggling with this question. help would be much appreciated

The cross section of the I-beams truss structure is 0.0031771m².
The forces from left to right are, 300 kN, 320 kN, 350 kN, 360 kN.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: The cross section is 0.0031771m².

Comment: The forces from left to right are, 300KN, 320KN, 350KN, 360KN

Comment: Why are you commenting on your question? [Edit] the question instead and post all the information in there. Since this is homework you need to show your attempt at a solution. Otherwise the question will be closed. Note 'k' for kilo, 'K' for kelvin.

Comment: I have added my attempts

Comment: Are your photos in the correct order? (Leave the original text-book question at the top - but a bigger image would be a big help.) You also need to state who's image that is. Give a book title, author and page number.